# How strange are Hölder domains?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $D$ be a Jordan domain. We assume that $D$ is a *Hölder domain.* Namely, there exists a Hölder continuous Riemann map $f$ such that $D=f(\mathbb{D})$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is an open unit disk.

It is known that quasidisks are Hölder domains. Hence, the boundaries of Hölder domains can be very wild. For example, the Koch snowflake is a Hölder domain.

**My question**

How strange is $D$?

I would like to know an example of Jordan domain which is Hölder and does not possesses both volume doubling property and the uniform poincare inequality. These two notions are fundamental in geometric analysis.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336224/volume-doubling-uniform-poincaré-counterexample/336730#336730  for the definition of the uniform poincare inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I should edit as you say.

Comment: while you are editing you may also check the spelling of **Hölder** :)

Comment: @PietroMajer Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: "Hölder older"... What is this...

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz Sorry. $f$ is a Riemann map. Therefore, $f$ is extended to a homeomorphism from $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ to $\bar{D}$.